# AngularJS + JavaScript: Enable Submit button only after email is valid and dropdown has a value selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have a form that has an input email field and a drop-down list populated by an array from database, at the bottom I have a submit button that is disabled when the form first opens.

I would like to learn how to enable this submit button, only if the input field contains a valid email, and the drop-down list has a selected value.

This is my small form:

```
<form name="form">
    <div class="container pt-5 pb-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @* Email Address *@
                <div>
                    <label for="email-address">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailID" ng-model="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" />                        
                </div>
                <br />
                @* Meetings  *@
                <div>
                    <label for="meeting-list">Current Available Meetings</label>
                    <select ng-model="selectedMeeting" ng-change="GetValue()">
                        <option ng-repeat="meeting in MeetingList" value="{{meeting.MeetingID}}">Meeting: {{meeting.MeetingName}}</option>
                        <option value="">--Select Meeting--</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="butClick" ng-click="SendMail();"/>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

If someone has some code that does something similar to what I need, and would not mind sharing it, that would be great.

Thank you kindly,
Erasmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'required' in the input and you can set [disabled] and set conditions in the submit button.

```html
    <form #formName="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="yourFunction(formName)">

    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailID" ng-model="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" required />

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-round" [disabled]="!formName.form.valid || form.pristine">Send mail</button>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Angular Reactive Forms like this

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
      <input placeholder="Enter your email" formControlName="email" required/>
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">SEND</button>
</form>
```

In app.component.ts file, you have to write

```
form: FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
    })
  }
```